# Embedded Strings in Interpolated Strings in F#

Tags: f#, string-interpolation

I cannot seem to figure out how I can embed strings inside an interpolated string in F#. Superficially, it is very similar to C#. For example, in C# I would write something like

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Truly, it is {(string.IsNullOrEmpty("") ? "" : "not ")}empty.");

//Result: Truly, it is empty.   OR   Truly, it is not empty.
```

The parentheses inside the curly brackets allow me to embed additional string literals within the interpolation expression.

I have attempted to replicate this in F# with

```fs
printfn $"Truly it is {(match (String.IsNullOrEmpty "l") with | true -> "" | false -> "not ")}empty."
```

The parentheses wrapping the interpolated expression do not accomplish the same thing, it seems. It suggests using an explicit `let` binding for the interpolated match expression, but for learning purposes I want to do it in a single line.

Is there a way to do this in F#, or am I stuck defining a `let` for the embedded ternary?

Comment: On a side note: the idiomatic way in F# is to use `if then else` instead of matching on a boolean.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just starting F# and still getting my legs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use triple-quoted strings:

```
printfn $"""Truly it is {match (String.IsNullOrEmpty "l") with | true -> "" | false -> "not "}empty."""
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!